# How to make s tooltip/text to always be on top of a pushpin/image in Bing Maps using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, bing-maps, pushpin

I am currently working on a ***WPF*** application using ***C#***. What I would like to do is that after I show a pushpin or an image on the map, a text or a tooltip is always shown on top of the pushpin/image, instead of hovering over it first.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add a UIElemet or some custom control to the map as a child and give it the same Location as your pushpin, but use margins to offset its position to where you want.